# javascript adding addEventListener dynamically to elements but the same function is called for all

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a script that is looking up an array called taggedElements from local storage. I iterate over the elements and then based on the properties I bind a click event to the element using an anon function. The issue that I am having is that the click event is bound but when I click the element the logCustomEvent function is always being passed the last "props" value so for example, both a tags fire the logCustomEvent function but when I console log the props value I see SpecialEvent 2 logged for both elements. If I add a more items to the array it seems to only use the last value in the function call.

My array looks something like this

```
let taggedElements = 
[
    {"cssSelector" : "#app > div > a", "props" : "SpecialEvent 1"},
    {"cssSelector" : "#app > div > p > a", "props" : "SpecialEvent 2"}
]
```

I iterate over the array and bind the click event like so

```
for(var elem of taggedElements){        
    let el = document.querySelector(elem.cssSelector);
    if(el){
        el.addEventListener("click", function(){
            logCustomEvent(elem.props)
        });
    }
}
```

The output in this example is two links on the page each with a click event that ideally would call the logCustomEvent function with a specific value. What is happening is two links with a click event that call the logCustomEvent function but both using the props value of the last item in the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the difference between `var` and `let/const` I believe that it is the issue. See this question: [What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var) . I beilive if you replace `var` in your `for` loop with `let` your issue will be resolved.

I recommend checking the documentation on mdn for further information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let